# Trouble evaluating $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos^4(x)}{x^2}$ without Hôpital's rule

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm having trouble evaluating this limit as $x$ approaches $0$ without using Hôpital's rule.

> $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos^4(x)}{x^2}$$

I'd appreciate any hints on how to proceed.

**EDIT:**
I totally forgot that

> $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$

I shall write my solution as punishment:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos^4(x)}{x^2}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1-\cos^2(x))\cdot(1+\cos^2(x))}{x^2}=$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos^2(x)}{x^2} \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} 1+\cos^2(x)=$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0}\Bigl(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\Bigr)^2\cdot2=1\cdot2=$$
$$=2$$

Comment: Factorize the numeartor.

Comment: What you have done is not a punishment but rather learning how to ask a good question. Good show!

Comment: It would be even shorter if you apply directly this other standard limit: $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac12.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** We have

$$1-\cos^{4}x = \left(1+\cos^2 x\right)\left(1-\cos^{2}x\right) .$$